# Tap outside of modal to close modal (react-native-modal)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-modal

Anyone has experience of implementing `react-native-modal`?
While I'm using it, modal isn't closed when I tap outside of modal.

Here is what I've tried

- Adding onBackdropPress(() => {this.props.hideModal()})
- Adding TouchableWithoutFeedback inside and outside of components
- and many other approaches...

Here is my the screen where I want to show my modal.

```js
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <ScrollView>
               // CONTENT HERE
               {this._renderModal()} //rendering modal here
               <FABs onFABsPress={this._showModal} /> // I open Modal when I press the FABs button
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    )
);

_renderModal = () => {
    return (
      <CameraImageSelectModal
        hideModal={this._hideModal}
        isModalVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}
        navigation={this.props.navigation}
      />
    )
}
```

Here is modal component : CameraImageSelectModal.js

```js
render() {
    let { isModalVisible } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        <Modal
          isVisible={isModalVisible}
          onBackdropPress={() => {console.log('hey')}}>
          transparent={true}>
          <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
            <View style={styles.modalTitleTextContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.modalTitleText}>Hello World</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.modalContentTextContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.modalContentText}></Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.modalButtonContainer}>
              <Button transparent onPress={this._handleCameraPress}>
                <Text style={[styles.modalText, styles.black]}>Camera</Text>
              </Button>
              <Button transparent onPress={this._handleAlbumPress}>
                <Text style={styles.modalText}>Album</Text>
              </Button>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured out why `onBackdropPress = {() => console.log("Pressed")}` didn't work..!!! onBackdropPress property was added since its version 3.xx and I was using 2.5.0 version.

So `yarn update react-native-modal` solved the issue.

If anyone encounters the problem that the library/component doesn't work as expected as you seen on documentation, try to check your package version number!

Cheers!

Comment: This would work if you want to use `react-native-modal` from @react-native-community. But it will not work with the inbuilt Modal of `react-native`

Answer (score 6):

I don't think the modal has that built in functionality, but you could create your own component that does. Here is a quick implementation. You might have to mess around with padding and margin to get it how you like, but this will allow the modal to be dismissed when pressing outside.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { Modal, StyleSheet, View, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native"

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    zIndex: 1,
    margin: 25,
    backgroundColor: "white"
  },
  background: {
    flex: 1
  },
  outerContainer: {
    position: "absolute", 
    top: 0, 
    left: 0, 
    right: 0, 
    bottom: 0, 
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
})

const MyModal = props => (
  <Modal transparent={true} animationType={"slide"} visible={props.visible} onRequestClose={() => props.onRequestClose()}>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.background} onPress={() => props.onRequestClose()} underlayColor={"transparent"}>
      <View />
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <View style={ styles.outerContainer }>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {props.children}
      </View>
    </View>
  </Modal>
)

export { MyModal }
```

Comment: Does this work?? Here is night now. I will test it on line tmr. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you were using the package react-native-modal. I thought you were just using react native's built in modal. This will not work with the package, but you could still use this.

Comment: No need to sorry, friend. :) I just figured out and posted my answer. I can't accept your answer for this question but your answer is definitely valuable! Voted up :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Modal
  isVisible={isModalVisible}
  customBackdrop={
    <View
      style={styles.backDropContainer}
      onTouchEnd={() => setModalVisible(false)}
    />
  }
  onBackdropPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
  <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
    <FlatList data={DATA} renderItem={() => <Text>hehehe</Text>} />
  </View>
</Modal>
```

Style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backDropContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    opacity: 0.5,
  },
  modalContainer: {
    flex: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the BackDrop just simple apply touchable Opacity on the background View and set it to active Opcaity={0} works perfectly:

```
 <TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.starModalmainContainer}
    activeOpacity={0}
    onPress={()=>{setIsVisible(false)}}>  
// Modal Content
</TouchableOpacity>
```