# Simple way to create a pop-up window with react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

The goal is a simple and clean implementation to build a pop-up window similar to the search-filters from the YouTube-App, see picture. Tapping on the half-transparent border should close the pop-up. The same pop-up is supposed to be called from several screens (within nested navigation-structures) and just give back the choices to the respective screen.

[image]

I did quite some search and documentation reading, so I seem to have the following four options:

1. Use an `Alert` window and heavily modifying the alert message, but this option does not allow me to cancel by clicking on the transparent area.
2. Using some promising-looking component which is very beta like [`react-native-popupwindow`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-popupwindow) is not really an option either.
3. Use a [`modal`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal) component which claims to be a simple way to present content above an enclosing view. According to [How to dim a background in react native modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058532/) and [Tap outside of modal to close modal (react-native-modal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775522)" this seems to be a possible option.
4. However, some people say that you should rather use [`Overlay`](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/overlay.html) and use [Modal only as a last resort](https://www.findbestopensource.com/product/brentvatne-react-native-overlay).

Please advice which of the solutions you tested in real life. What do you suggest? Maybe there is even an easier solution?

Related question(s) here on StackOverflow:

- [Transparent overlay in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638739/)

Comment: Seriously you can use a modal for this purpose. It is really easy and can implement what you want without any problem. Also can call it using redux and with dynamic content.

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara Thanks for the hint, I am still curious on comments on the other options.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modal is totally your way to go.

My personal choice would be https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal which has the best performances and flexibility overall.

Comment: I don't know why to use a library and make your app heavy when you can easily implement this with simple several lines of code.

Comment: Again, it has better performances and more features included. It is part of the well-known react-native-community libraries.

Comment: I have no doubt about react native community libraries. But for such a small use of modal, why should you use a feature rich library?